# accessing low level attributes of a NSStream

Tags: cocoa, hardware-interface, nsstream

I have a Keyspan PCI to RS-422 adapter that I'm using to connect old serial devices to a Macintosh. I would like to use NSInputStream and NSOutputStream to read and write so that I can take advantage of asynchronous nonblocking I/O since there will be several devices attached to this system that each have their own idiosyncrasies.

My question is how can I access some low level parameters for the devices using a NSStream (baud rate, count of stop bits, parity, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I researched everything before I asked the question, but the answer was in another class (NSFilehandle).